# Typescript overload signature pass object and value

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can accept object or value.

```
export function A( param: string );
export function A({ param }: { param: string }) {

}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> typescript overload signature is not compatible with function
>   implementation

What is the problem?

```
export function A( param: string ): void
export function A({ param, ...rest  }: { param: string}): void
export function A( param: string | { param: string = "initial", ...rest }) : void{

}
```

Comment: You can only define overloads in type declarations. Javascript does not support method overloading and typescript does not know how to compile the multiple methods into a single one. This means that the actual implementation must contain a single method that works for every overloaded signature in the type declaration.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger you can have several overloads, but a single implementation

Comment: Is that not what I said? The single implementation must have a signature that matches all of the overloads, because typescript doesn't know how to automatically create that method.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger Sorry I understood from your comment that you can only define overloads in declarations and can't implement a function with multiple signatures in typescript. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have several overloads, the last one is the implementation overload. The implementation overload is not visible from the outside and must be compatible with all other overloads. In your case the signatures should look like this:

```
export function A(param: string): void
export function A(param: { param: string, otherProp?: string }): void
export function A(paramOrObj: string | { param: string, otherProp?: string } = { param: "initial"}): void {
    // If param is not string destructure
    if (typeof paramOrObj !== "string") {
        let { param, ...rest } = paramOrObj;
    } else {
        // otherwise use the string value
        let param = paramOrObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a problem. When I am adding a default value to the object and try to use the rest operator it's not working.

Comment: export function A( param: string ): void
export function A({ param }: { param: string, ...rest }): void
export function A( param: string | { param: string = "initial", ...rest }) : void{

}

Comment: Whoops, didn't see your answer.  Deleted mine.

Comment: @undefined edited, hope this is close to what you wanted. Sorry for the delay got called from the PC

Comment: Thank you very much